# How do I change the position of an object in A-Frame using setAttribute?

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

I am facing this issue in 0.8.0. My

```
<a-sphere id="ball" position="-1 0.59 -4"></a-sphere>
```

already exists in the `<a-scene>` of `<body>`. On click of this ball, I want its position to change to, say -3 0.59 -3. I have tried

```
document.getElementById("ball").setAttribute('position', '-3 0.59 -3')
document.getElementById("ball").setAttribute('position', {x:-3, y:0.59, z:-3}) 
document.getElementById("ball").object3D.position.set('-3 0.59 -3')
```

but none of them seem to work.

I am building an app where the position of the ball changes to the point where the cursor is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Both methods:

```
document.getElementById("ball").setAttribute('position', '-3 0.59 -3')
document.getElementById("ball").setAttribute('position', {x:-3, y:0.59, z:-3})
```

are correct and move the ball to the selected position. Check it out in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ufsm69q/).

---

It's possible, that You: 
**1.** Call the methods before the scene is loaded, therefore the ball can't be grabbed. 
**2.** Didn't set up the cursor or the mouse to be working with the rendered objects.  
 Setting up the mouse is easy - just add the `cursor` component to the scene:

```
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
```

Be sure to check out the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/cursor.html#sidebar) on the cursor.

**3.** Didn't properly set up the event listeners for the click, which I've done like this:

```
 AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
   init: function() {
      this.el.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
        //do Your thing here
      })
   }
 })
```

If you're unfamiliar with the component system, make sure to check them [out](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/entity-component-system.html#extensibility).